# Why gl.readPixels() is not working?

Tags: javascript, webgl

I have been trying to implement clipping and capping using WebGL. To do this i have to use the stencil buffer to restrict the drawing of the clipping plane so that only the portion which is inside of an object get drawn.

Firstly, i have been trying to work with stencil buffer. My objective is to check if `gl.clearStencil()` and `gl.clear()` update the value of stencil buffer. Here is the test sample to check it -

```
    var contextAttributes = gl.getContextAttributes();
    var haveStencilBuffer = contextAttributes.stencil;

    var bitPlane = gl.getParameter(gl.STENCIL_BITS);

    gl.stencilMask(0xFF);
    gl.clearStencil(10);
    gl.clear(gl.STENCIL_BUFFER_BIT);
    gl.enable( gl.STENCIL_TEST );
    gl.stencilFunc( gl.ALWAYS, 0, 0);

    var stencils = new Uint8Array((window.innerHeight/2) * (window.innerWidth/2));
    gl.readPixels(0, 0, window.innerWidth/2, window.innerHeight/2, gl.STENCIL_INDEX, gl.UNSIGNED_BYTE, stencils);
```

i get `haveStencil = true` and `bitPlane = 8`, so its confirmed that there is a stencil buffer with 8 bit storage for each pixel.

But I have found that the value stored in `stencils`array are all `Zero` when i have set the clear value as `10`. I have checked that the `gl.readPixels()` function does not populate the `stencils` array. This code looks accurate to me. What could actually go wrong here?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't believe you can read the stencil with `gl.readPixels`. When I try your example I get

```
WebGL: INVALID_ENUM: readPixels: invalid format
```

But here's a working example with the stencil. Maybe you can see what you did differently. For one it explicitly asks for a stencil buffer. You should do that if you want to make sure you get one. Otherwise it's up to the implementation.

This code sets a rectangular area of the stencil buffer to 10 using the scissor test and clear. It then turns off the scissor test and turns on the stencil test and draws a fullscreen quad. It should only draw where the stencil was set to 10. We then reverse the test and draw again in another color which will draw everywhere but there the stencil is 10. I'm using [twgl.js](http://twgljs.org) because WebGL is too verbose but I hope the code is clear.

```js
// explictly ask for a stencil buffer
var gl = document.createElement("canvas").getContext(
  "webgl", {stencil: true});
document.body.appendChild(gl.canvas);

// set part of the stencil (using the scissor to be easy)
gl.enable(gl.SCISSOR_TEST);
gl.scissor(10, 20, 50, 60);
gl.stencilMask(0xFF);
gl.clearStencil(10);
gl.clear(gl.STENCIL_BUFFER_BIT);
gl.disable(gl.SCISSOR_TEST);

// Now draw a fullscreen quad with the stencil test on
gl.enable(gl.STENCIL_TEST);
gl.stencilFunc(gl.EQUAL, 10, 0xFF);
var programInfo = twgl.createProgramInfo(gl, ["vs", "fs"]);

var arrays = {
  position: [-1, -1, 0, 1, -1, 0, -1, 1, 0, -1, 1, 0, 1, -1, 0, 1, 1, 0],
};
var bufferInfo = twgl.createBufferInfoFromArrays(gl, arrays);

gl.useProgram(programInfo.program);
twgl.setBuffersAndAttributes(gl, programInfo, bufferInfo);
twgl.setUniforms(programInfo, { color: [1,0,0,1] });
twgl.drawBufferInfo(gl, gl.TRIANGLES, bufferInfo);

// and again with the test reversed
gl.stencilFunc(gl.NOTEQUAL, 10, 0xFF);

twgl.setUniforms(programInfo, { color: [0,1,0,1] });
twgl.drawBufferInfo(gl, gl.TRIANGLES, bufferInfo);
```

```css
canvas { border: 1px solid black; }
```

```html
<script id="vs" type="notjs">
attribute vec4 position;
void main() {
  gl_Position = position;
}
  </script>
  <script id="fs" type="notjs">
precision mediump float;
uniform vec4 color;
void main() {
  gl_FragColor = color;  
}
  </script>
  <script src="https://twgljs.org/dist/twgl.min.js"></script>
```